# Using GoogleTest with Bullseye to generate a test report

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, bullseye

I am trying to use `GoogleTest` and `bullseye` for testing C application code. I am in a [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) environment using an i686-type processor. I got the `gtest` and `bullseye` libraries. The process for writing stubs and test code is also understandable. The step where I'm facing issues is making changes in the `makefile` to get the binary and coverage file.

I went through the official documentation available for `gtest` and `bullseye`, but I'm not able to quite grasp the process.

If anybody has experienced the same situation and finally got the walk-through, please share with me. It'll be very helpful.

Comment: bullseye is independent of the unit test framework. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For googleTest, just add library and include path, add `-I${GTEST_DIR}/include -L${GTEST_DIR}/lib/.libs/libgtest.a` when doing gcc compiling.

Or if you are using automake to generate of Makefile, add two lines to `Makefile.am` which can be used by automake also works.

```
autotest_LDADD=@LIBS@ ${GTEST_DIR}/lib/.libs/libgtest.a
autotest_CXXFLAGS=@CXXFLAGS@ -I${GTEST_DIR}/include
```

The project name is autotest, and ${GTEST_DIR} should be a environment variable before you compile.

Never used bullseye, but it should be close to this.